# What is the origin of Ruby's block syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, programming-languages

Ruby has an interesting syntax for blocks (arguments between pipes followed by a sequence of statements):

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |x|
    puts x
end
```

Rust uses a similar syntax as well:

```
arr.sort_by_key(|a| {
    let intermediate_value = some_function(a);
    intermediate_value + 10
});
```

I'm wondering if this syntax predates Ruby (particularly putting arguments between pipes, which I believe I've seen elsewhere but am not sure where), and if so, what languages use it?

I believe that Smalltalk also uses pipes, but for object initialization, and I can't find any other examples on Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's creator, "Matz", has said Ruby's design was inspired by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.

From this list, I would say it's most likely from Smalltalk, Eiffel, and Lisp. Examples:

Smalltalk

```
#(1 2 3 4 5) inject: 0 into: [:sum :number | sum + number]
```

```
#(1 2 3 4 5) fold: [:product :number | product * number]
```

Lisp

```lisp
(let ((data #(1 2 3 4 5)))     ; the array
  (values (reduce #'+ data)       ; sum
          (reduce #'* data)))     ; product
```

```lisp
(loop for i in '(1 2 3 4 5) sum i)
```

Eiffel

```
class
    APPLICATION

create
    make

feature {NONE}

    make
        local
            test: ARRAY [INTEGER]
        do
            create test.make_empty
            test := <<5, 1, 9, 7>>
            io.put_string ("Sum: " + sum (test).out)
            io.new_line
            io.put_string ("Product: " + product (test).out)
        end

    sum (ar: ARRAY [INTEGER]): INTEGER
            -- Sum of the items of the array 'ar'.
        do
            across
                ar.lower |..| ar.upper as c
            loop
                Result := Result + ar [c.item]
            end
        end

    product (ar: ARRAY [INTEGER]): INTEGER
            -- Product of the items of the array 'ar'.
        do
            Result := 1
            across
                ar.lower |..| ar.upper as c
            loop
                Result := Result * ar [c.item]
            end
        end

end
```